# Cannot apply custom ribbon to a form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ribbonx

I want to apply custom ribbon to some of the forms in my database and I can't make it work. I decided to start by hiding the ribbon entirely, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/how-to-hide-the-ribbon-when-access-starts). I created the USysRibbon table, and added the following RibbonXML:

```
<CustomUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/CustomUI">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="true"/>
</CustomUI>
```

Then I reloaded the database, assigned this ribbon to "Ribbon" property of my form, saved it and reloaded the database again.

At first I though that the issue might be in the XML itself, so I tried changing 
 CustomUI xmlns property to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui", and when this didn't work, I tried to remove all tabs using Customize Ribbon menu, exported the XML and pasted it to USysRibbon. This also didn't work. Finally, the form that I tried to apply this to had subforms, so I tried setting the same Ribbon to all subforms, and even that didn't work.

I'm using Office365, version 1902.

Applying custom ribbon to entire database using USysRibbons also doesn't work.

Any ideas what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml looks ok, but the url for the schema is wrong - it is caps senstive.

So, try this:

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/Customui">
```

You existing tags look ok. So you can now set this ribbon as system wide. In fact, I recommend that you MAKE SURE you remove the ribbons on the forms, since you don't want to have the system wide ribbon set and then the same ribbon set in forms (they will often not load correct if you do this).

Note that in place of setting the ribbon for every form, in file->options->current database, you can select the ribbon for the overall application.

Once you change above, exit the database, and then re-load. If you turn on user interface errors, then access would have spit out a error message telling you that the xml is ill-formed.
To turn on user interface errors:File->options->Client settings.
Scroll down to [x] Show add-in user interface errors. (check this box).
By checking this box, when I tried your xml it spit out a error message, but it did look correct. But the url is/was caps sensitive.

## Edit

This works for me:

```
<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"">
  <ribbon startFromScratch=""true""/>
</customUI>"
```

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out the option to turn on the user interface errors, I really missed on that one. However, the URL you provided also doesn't seem to work, so I'll keep googling the errors and let you know.

Comment: see my edit, I posted some xml that works for me  - it looks like case sensitive is still biting you.

Comment: You have a capital C for customUI - check that issue.

Comment: Thanks - and don't get me started in how much and often caps in JavaScript, or xml  defs for the ribbon bites me! - we just have to be extra careful and use extra caution  at a higher level then I am used to. So, real caution here. But the UI errors turned  on will at least tell you if there's  something wrong.